# PayPal API integrating into server

Tags: java, paypal, integration, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to integrate my server with the api,
I test it on

https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/openid/java?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox

in the third step, when I copy the code from the redirectUri, paste it instead AUTH-CODE and press the "try it" button, I get the message "invalid Json response recieved"..
I don't understand why, what Is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

paypal api is very restricted. You need to have all products with prices, tax, shipping method and much more.

best will be if you can add json request so we can check it.

PS. you have your auth codes? That ones are only examples.